# Confused by variables and methods of ruby

Tags: ruby

How does ruby call `varz` method by using `varz[:foo]`?

```
class Component
  class << self
    def varz
      @varz ||= Hash.new
    end
  end
end

Component.varz[:foo] = 'bar'
puts Component.varz # {:foo=>"bar"}
```

Comment: Where do you get your knowledge from? I suggest a good book. It will clear many confusions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cut it in the wrong way. `Component.varz` is a method call. To the result of it (which is a hash), `[:foo] =` applies. The `[]` and `[]=` methods are special in that you don't put a period between the receiver and the method.

Comment: "to it (which is a hash)" - so is it a method call or a hash? :) Indexer applies to *result* of said method call, not to call itself.

Comment: I think this is a better answer. Because I know how ruby treat class as object and how it returns value, but I'm just confused how it use varz method with [] which you have explained above.

Answer (score 3):

**class << self**  is used to define the class method,that will be called on the class.

where as @varz represents the instance variable. You might wonder, then why this instance object is doing in class method? This is because class itself is instance of **Class**.

One more thing to note, in ruby method returns it's last statement. So in your case **Component.varz** returning the instance variable @varz which is of hash type.

```
Component.varz[:foo] = 'bar'
```

this add the key-value pair foo and 'bar' to hash.

And finally,

```
p Component.varz
```

you are printing the value returened by the varz method.

Comment: Your answer is very good, but I think the better answer is below. Because I know how ruby treat class as object and how it returns value, but I'm confused how it use varz method with [].

Comment: You are not using varz method directly, you are using the object return by the varz method.

Comment: Yeah, I got it now. Thanks a lot.